# Can an individual invest in stocks outside his country?

Tags: united-states, investing, pakistan

Can I can invest in New York Stock Exchange from Pakistan? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: As a canadian, I once bought Nintendo actions (in Japan). I had to deal with a broker who had a licence in Japan to be able to buy and sell there. Cons : It will cost you bigger brokers fees since they charge you for being in another country. Pro : If you believe in the company you're investing in, (like I did with Nintendo), then it may be worth.

Comment: This would really be a question for the Law site, since it depends on the laws of individual countries.  For US citizens, it's easy (trivially, just buy international stock mutual funds); for North Koreans (who are not part of the ruling junta) probably impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is best answered by your brokerage firm. Institutional investors do overseas investing all the time. However, for individuals restrictions and additional taxes may apply. First and foremost, your brokerage firm should have some agreement worked out with New York Stock Exhchange and both the governments involved.

Hence, some brokers will allow while others not.